# dynamic mass generation

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I found it alittle tricky, so i just posted it so that i could be corrected if i am wrong. To my understanding, dynamic mass generation means ZERO bare mass while the contribution coming from loops make the particle massive. Hence, essentially, it is with the same renormalization procedure but with ZERO bare mass. Please let me know if there is anything wrong in my understanding, or even if i have understood the concept correctly. I shall really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is basically correct.

In the context of Dirac fermions, the bare mass being zero or not is a big deal. The action with zero bare mass observes the global axial symmetry, whereas the non-zero one violates the global axial symmetry.

Dynamic mass generation means that the global axial symmetry is dynamically broken (in addition to the ABJ quantum anomaly effects).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, i really appreciate it.